# Mapping PostgreSQL text[][] type and Java type

Tags: java, string, postgresql, jdbc, multidimensional-array

I have a Postgres table containing a column of type `text[][]`. In JDBC code I've used a String array, but an exception told me that these two do not match. If there's no mapping between these types, could you suggest a Postgres type for a string arrays?

This is the code:

```
String list = "'{";
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            list+=prodotti[i]+",";
        }
        list+="}'";

        preparedStm.setString(4, list);
```

Comment: Could you specify your case further by inserting a bit of code?

Comment: A `String` array (or `String[]`) does not match with `text[][]`, if it would work, it would be either `text[]` or you should use `String[][]` in Java. I am not saying that it will work, but at least match up your datatypes.

Comment: You should include sample data and the exact error message. Would make it easier to help you.

Comment: the error just told me that the column is of type text[] but expression is of type character varying. I've edit my message with the part of code that throws exception

Comment: The **verbatim** error message should be the key part of your question. The part where `text` and `character varying` are mentioned could help to solve this quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand multi-dimensional PostgreSQL array types consider the following [quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION):

> The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of
> dimensions either. Arrays of a particular element type are all
> considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of
> dimensions. So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in
> `CREATE TABLE` is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time
> behavior.

Internally, the types `text[]`, `text[][]` are the same to PostgreSQL. **If** the column actually contains 2-dimensional text arrays, you'll have to match the dimensions in Java. But it could contain 1- or 3-dimensional arrays as well. PostgreSQL would allow it.

Also note that `text` and `character varying` (`varchar`) are **different data types** in PostgreSQL (while doing largely the same when `varchar` has no length modifier). Start by reading about [character types in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html).