# Slow handling of 2-dimensional arrays in plpgsql

Tags: performance, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-arrays, type-2-dimension

I am programming a stored procedure in PostgreSQL. The algorithm should handle a 2 dimensional array of `double precision` numbers.

As far as I have investigated array operations in Postgres are generic and quite heavy. The simple example I'm trying to prove has an excessive computational cost.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fill_2d_array( rows integer, cols integer) 
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$

DECLARE

img double precision[][];

i integer; j integer;
cont integer;

BEGIN

img  := ARRAY( SELECT 0 FROM generate_series(1, filas * columnas) ) ; 
cont:= 0;
For i IN 1..rows LOOP
    For j IN 1..cols LOOP
        img[i * cols + j] := (i * cols + j)::double precision;
        cont := cont + 1;
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;

return cont;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Can someone help me find an alternative path or an improvement to handle two-dimensional arrays?

Comment: I can't decypher what are you trying to accomplish... Why can't you just use arrayagg() instead of loops?

Comment: `filas` and `columnas` are undefined. I suppose that should be `rows` and `cols`? And please describe what trying to do. Since you are only returning an integer, the whole operation seems pointless?

Answer (score 2):

### Procedural function

#### Basic problems

Declaring the dimensions of an array variable, like `float8[][]` for a 2-dimensional array, only serves documentation. Consider details in this related answer:

- [Mapping PostgreSQL text[][] type and Java type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743841/mapping-postgresql-text-type-and-java-type/10745524#10745524)

You confused 1-dimenstional and 2-dimensional arrays. While declaring a 2-dimenstional array (to no effect), you only make it out to be a 1-dimensional array.

To initialize an array, use [`array_fill()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE):

```
img := array_fill(0, ARRAY[rows,cols])
```

This example produces a 2-dimensional array - as opposed to your faulty statement, producing a 1-dimensional array:

```
img  := ARRAY( SELECT 0 FROM generate_series(1, rows* cols) );  -- wrong!
```

The displayed array subscripts `img[i * cols + j]` hardly make sense. The maximum would be twice of what you initialized, resulting in "out-of-bound" errors. I suppose you mean `img[i][j]`.

#### Working version

Everything put together it could work like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_array_fill(rows integer, cols integer, OUT img float8[][]) 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   i int;
   j int;
BEGIN
   img := array_fill(0, ARRAY[rows,cols]);

   FOR i IN 1 .. rows LOOP
       FOR j IN 1 .. cols LOOP
           img[i][j] := (i * cols + j)::float8;
       END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_array_fill(2,3);
```

Result:

```
{{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

To make the function useful, return the produced array. Using an [`OUT` parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) for that.

### Superior set-based version

Looping and individual assignments are comparatively slow in PL/pgSQL. See:

- [Function Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8189/3684)

Array handling performs particularly poorly as explained by @Craig in this related answer:

- [Why is PostgreSQL array access so much faster in C than in PL/pgSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992339/why-is-postgresql-array-access-so-much-faster-in-c-than-in-pl-pgsql/16996606#16996606)

A set-based approach used to scale better with old versions. But the difference is mostly gone with modern Postgres.

#### Aggregate function for multi-dimensional arrays

In Postgres **9.4** or older, we needed a custom aggregate function. [`array_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) only produced 1-dimensional arrays. Since Postgres **9.5** we can just use built-in functions. See.

- [Initial array in function to aggregate multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832973/initial-array-in-function-to-aggregate-multi-dimensional-array/9845460#9845460)

SQL function doing the the same as the above:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_array_fill_sql(_rows integer, _cols integer)
  RETURNS float8[][]  -- 2nd dim only for documentation
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT array_agg(arr1) AS arr2
FROM  (
   SELECT array_agg((i * $2 + j)::float8) AS arr1
   FROM        generate_series(1, _rows) i
   CROSS  JOIN generate_series(1, _cols) j
   GROUP  BY i
   ORDER  BY i
   ) sub
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_array_fill_sql(2,3);
```

Result:

```
{{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

Comment: A access to array field is relatively fast (not fast as C sure), but array update large array is terribly slow due fact, so (in this moment) a arrays (and all objects in Postgres) are immutable structures. Any update means creating new one. This feature will be fixed (maybe) - patch is in commitfest http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRB8=cGxi1XAtjiTD0Sn3ZqYkTomEd96OdzGPUVs7tX9Cg@mail.gmail.com

Comment: @PavelStehule: I have read about it. Exciting news. Good job! :)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter  `SELECT f_array_fill_sql(3,4);` should return `{{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}} ` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=42068d68736e3447f7c1014f1493eb8a

Comment: @Mark: That was a typo and should have read `SELECT f_array_fill_sql(2,3);` like in the previous example. Anyway, this answer is very old and partly outdated. I updated a bit and removed some obsolete bits.

Answer (score 0):

[db fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2de10f811b38e5dbc5893bdd99a07b52)
In postgresql 14, `array_cat` changed. see:  [postgresql14 changes](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/97f73a978fc1aca59c6ad765548ce0096d95a923?diff=split)
also https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAKFQuwbKPYOuaexih1fMDPKa7kTjLSVjNdWCRHn7iJ2%2BoukpHg%40mail.gmail.com

Then from the [test doc](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/test/regress/expected/polymorphism.out;h=2c3bb0a60b0250a7d1ce9dba9acb76b867623a32;hb=9e38c2bb5093ceb0c04d6315ccd8975bd17add66) (around line 732).
Then in Postgresql 14, we need to recreate aggregate again.

```
create or replace aggregate array_agg_mult(anycompatiblearray) (
sfunc = array_cat,
stype = anycompatiblearray,
initcond = '{}'
);


create or replace function
    f_array_fill_sql(_rows integer,_cols integer)
returns float8[][] AS
$func$
    select array_agg_mult(array[arr1]) as arr2
    from (
        select array_agg((i * $2 + j )::float8) arr1
            from generate_series(1,$1) i
        cross join generate_series(1,$2) j
        group by i order by i
        ) sub
$func$ language sql;
```