# How to extract row from int[][] as int[] in postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm totally confused about what sql array indexing does and what the return types of indexing `[]` should be.

I have a 3,2 array:

```
select ARRAY[
   [1,1],
   [2,2],
   [3,3]];

--> {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}}
```

(BTW, pgadmin3 says this is an "array integer[]", not "array integer[][]").

Let's say I want to extract the first row (indexes start at 1 right?):

```
-- A
select (ARRAY[
   [1,1],
   [2,2],
   [3,3]])[1];
--> NULL
```

Huh? Why not `{1,1}` (of type `int[]`).

```
-- B
select (ARRAY[
   [1,1],
   [2,2],
   [3,3]])[1][:];

--> {{1,1}}
```

... seems legit. But:

```
-- C
select (ARRAY[
   [1,1],
   [2,2],
   [3,3]])[1][:][1];
--> {}
```

why is this different to A?

And how can I extract a row from an int[][] (1d array) as an int[] (1d array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to extract row from int[][] as int[] in postgres

By aggregation of unnested elements:

```
select array_agg(elem)
from unnest(array[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]) elem;

   array_agg   
---------------
 {1,1,2,2,3,3}
(1 row)
```

You can find more information in this post: [How to get the dimensionality of an ARRAY column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39436189/1995738)

---

If you want to get the second subarray:

```
with my_data(id, arr) as (
values
(1, array[
   [1,1],
   [2,2],
   [3,3]]),
(2, array[
   [1,1,11],
   [2,2,22],
   [3,3,33]])
)

select array_agg(elem)
from my_data, 
unnest(arr[2:2]) elem
group by id;

 array_agg 
-----------
 {2,2}
 {2,2,22}
(2 rows)
```

Note1. The notation `[2:2]` means a slice from 2nd element to 2nd element, so it points to the second subarray.

Note 2. Multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions.

Comment: This gets all the rows. What if I want the second row?

Comment: A '{{ ... }}' is a 2d array. I want a 1d array (the row). It makes a difference because arr[1] gives NULL is arr is 2d, or the element if its 1d.

Comment: Use the first tip, the answer modified again.

Comment: Its a little dangerous because it relies on the row width being fixed and known ahead of time.  Arrays can vary in their dimension sizes within table's row.

Comment: No, it doesn't rely on subarray widths. See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the klin's answer and using function provided [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Unnest_multidimensional_array) (with some fixes):

```
-- drop operator if exists -> (anyarray, int);
-- drop function if exists array_by_index(anyarray, int);
-- drop function if exists reduce_dim(anyarray);

create or replace function reduce_dim(anyarray)
returns setof anyarray as
$function$
declare
  s $1%type;
begin
  if ($1 = '{}') or ($1 is null) then
    return;
  else
    foreach s slice 1 in array $1 loop
      return next s;
    end loop;
    return;
  end if;
end;
$function$
language plpgsql immutable;

create function array_by_index(anyarray, int) returns anyarray
  language sql
  immutable
as $$
  select case when count(*) = 1 then reduce_dim($1[$2:$2]) else array_agg(x) end 
  from reduce_dim($1[$2:$2]) x
$$;

create operator -> (procedure = array_by_index, leftarg = anyarray, rightarg = int);

select 
  array[[[1,1],[2,2]],[[3,3],[4,4]]]->2,
  array[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]->3,
  array[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]->3->1;
╔═══════════════╤══════════╤══════════╗
║   ?column?    │ ?column? │ ?column? ║
╠═══════════════╪══════════╪══════════╣
║ {{3,3},{4,4}} │ {5,6}    │ {5}      ║
╚═══════════════╧══════════╧══════════╝
```