# How to assign value to a multi dimensional array in postgresql procedure

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array, plpgsql

I would like to assign values dynamically into an array using PostgreSQL.

what I have done so far:-
I have declared `_tmp_user_data` as `_tmp_user_data character varying[][];`
and I have written the array assignment inside a posgresql `cursor`

```
    _counter := 0;
    open _user_data_cursor for execute _sql_user_data;
    Loop
        FETCH _user_data_cursor INTO _tmp_user_name, _tmp_crop_name;
        If found Then
            RAISE NOTICE '_tmp_crop_name name:%', _tmp_crop_name;
            _tmp_user_data[_counter]['user_name'] := _tmp_user_name;
        else
            exit;
        end if;
        _counter := _counter + 1;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE _user_data_cursor;
```

I have been getting the following error

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "user_name"

Comment: Please provide a *complete* function or procedure including the header. And always your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core problem is that Postgres arrays only accept **integer subscripts**, not strings.

```
_tmp_user_data[_counter]['user_name']
```

Something like this could work:

```
_tmp_user_data[_counter][1]  -- _counter being an integer variable
```

[Start reading the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html)

There is no data `type varying[][]` (though that spelling is tolerated). The data type is `character varying[]` (or `varchar[]`). Postgres arrays use the same *type* for any number of dimensions. See:

- [Use string[][] with ngpsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314338/use-string-with-ngpsql/34315117#34315117)

And Postgres arrays are 1-based by default. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING)

> By default PostgreSQL uses a one-based numbering convention for arrays, that is, an array of ***`n`*** elements starts with `array[1]` and ends with `array[`***`n`***`]`.

Related:

- [Normalize array subscripts for 1-dimensional array so they start with 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011569/normalize-array-subscripts-for-1-dimensional-array-so-they-start-with-1)

Typically, you don't need an explicit cursor to loop in PL/pgSQL. See:

- [Truncating all tables in a Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829158/truncating-all-tables-in-a-postgres-database/12082038#12082038)
- [Loop on tables with PL/pgSQL in Postgres 9.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266345/loop-on-tables-with-pl-pgsql-in-postgres-9-0/15278973#15278973)

And more often than not, there is a superior solution without any looping at all ...