# plpgsql function taking a multi-dimensional array as parameter

Tags: arrays, postgresql, null, plpgsql

I'm trying to run a plpgsql function on a multi-dimensional array column (`int[][]`) in a select query.

The function is as such:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.reduce_to_percentages(int[][])
RETURNS float[] AS
$function$
DECLARE
  s int[];
  a float[];
BEGIN
    FOREACH s SLICE 1 IN ARRAY $1 LOOP
        a := a || s[2]::float / s[1]::float;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN a;
END;
$function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

The following query works:

```
SELECT reduce_to_percentages(ARRAY[ARRAY[100, 20], ARRAY[300, 50]]);
```

So does the following query:

```
SELECT reduce_to_percentages((SELECT counts FROM objects LIMIT 1));
```

But the following query provides the function with a `null` value, and causes an exception when trying to `FOREACH` over `$1`:

```
SELECT reduce_to_percentages(counts) FROM objects;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* fix the error by checking for `NULL` values [like @klin provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37753738/939860).
But that's putting lipstick on a pig. Rewrite the function to replace the procedural loop with a set-based solution. Typically faster (especially when used in the context of an outer query), simpler and automatically null-safe:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.reduce_to_percentages(int[])
  RETURNS float[] AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY (SELECT $1[d][2]::float / $1[d][1]
              FROM   generate_subscripts($1,1) d)
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Related:

- [Unnest array by one level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137112/unnest-array-by-one-level/8142998#8142998)

Notes:

- Casting the *dividend* to `float` is enough. `float / integer` returns `float` automatically.
- There is no data type `int[][]`. Just `int[]`. Postgres allows the notation, but ignores additional array dimensions for array types, since the data type itself is the same for all dimensions. Details:

  - [mapping postgresql text[][] type and Java type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743841/mapping-postgresql-text-type-and-java-type/10745524#10745524)
- Make the function `IMMUTABLE` (since it *is*) for better performance and to allow indexing. Related:

  - [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behaviour of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569415/how-do-immutable-stable-and-volatile-keywords-effect-behaviour-of-function/28573737#28573737)
  - [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

---

***Alternatively***, you could declare your function as `STRICT` (synonym: `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT`). Minor difference: it returns `NULL` for NULL input, not an empty array (`'{}'`) like the above.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.reduce_to_percentages(int[][])
  RETURNS float[] AS
$function$
 ...
$function$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html)

> `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` or `STRICT` indicates that the function
>   always returns null whenever any of its arguments are null. If this
>   parameter is specified, the function is not executed when there are
>   null arguments; instead a null result is assumed automatically.

But the simple SQL function above is preferable for multiple reasons.

Comment: Wow, very thorough explanation, thank you very much!!!

As for `int[][]` being ignored, I did know that but for my own read-ability I wrote the function to be more explicit in the type of value it accepts.

Two things that I still don't understand: 1) what is the difference between immutable and volatile functions, what makes this function immutable? 2) why did @klin's answer solve my problem? He only added a case for null values, which returns an empty list, but using his function made my query work (for non-null values).

Comment: @YotamOfek: Ad 1.) [I added a link to more explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569415/how-do-immutable-stable-and-volatile-keywords-effect-behaviour-of-function/28573737#28573737). Ad 2.) The error you saw was raised by the `FOREACH` construct that does not work for NULL input.

Comment: *putting lipstick on a pig* - you have a specific sense of humor, but I like it. You know that your solution is faster, or just guessing?

Comment: @klin: I wrote *typically*. And yes, I *know* from many benchmarks. It also makes sense, given the underlying mechanisms. I assume you are aware that ["putting lipstick on a pig" is a rhetorical expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipstick_on_a_pig). No offense intended. And your answer would be the lipstick in this, not the pig. I'll comment on the benchmark under your answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the function body just check if the argument is not null. If you want to return an empty array for a null argument then add an initial value for the variable `a` in declare section (otherwise the function will return null).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.reduce_to_percentages(int[][])
RETURNS float[] AS
$function$
DECLARE
  s int[];
  a float[] = '{}';     -- initial value
BEGIN
    IF $1 IS NOT NULL THEN
        FOREACH s SLICE 1 IN ARRAY $1 LOOP
            a := a || s[2]::float / s[1]::float;
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
    RETURN a;
END;
$function$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

---

I have done a simple test. This is a modest setup:

```
create table test (val int[]);
insert into test
select (array[array[ri(100), ri(100)], array[ri(100), ri(100)]])
from generate_series(1, 1000000);
```

`ri(100)` is my function returning random integer between 1-100. 
So the table contains a million rows with an array of two arrays of two integers in one column.
I tried the test to be as simple and *typical* as possible.

The following query has been executed 10 times with Erwin's function and 10 times with my variant:

```
select sum(v[1]), sum(v[2])
from (
    select reduce_to_percentages(val) v
    from test
    ) s;
```

Average execution time of ten tests:

- Erwin's function     11940 ms
- klin's function       4750 ms

Maybe my function is a pig with lipstick on its snout but it is a speedy one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the column value is not null, and is defined as such. That's why using a subquery works.

Comment: No, the subquery works because you have `limit 1` (and the selected value is not null). Just try the function.

Comment: It works! Can you please explain why? I mean, as far as I can see in what you changed in the function, you're simply returning an empty array in the event of a null value. How does it end up working, as opposed to not checking for null? Thanks!!

Comment: Your original function was not prepared for null values and threw an exception in `foreach`. Your only trouble was to not allow to execute `foreach` for null values.

Comment: I like benchmarks. Effective performance depends on many factors - as I am sure you know. You tested with array-length 2. For just two elements, an array type would be a big waste. Separate columns would make more sense. An array makes sense for a sizeable (variable) number of elements. Repeat your benchmark with 20 or 100 elements and you'll see the set-based solution scales much better. (I tested on 9.5!) PL/pgSQL plays into this, too. Sometimes reduces overhead, but can be much more expensive where a simple SQL alternative can be inlined in the context of the outer query.

Comment: While being at it, test your function with volatility `STABLE` or `IMMUTABLE`. Depending on the test, this can make a substantial difference ...

Comment: I knew that with increasing cardinality of the arrays, the cost of the call of `generate_subscripts()` will be better compensated. I only wanted to point out that categorical statements sometimes tend to be risky. Making the function `immutable` makes sense mainly when we are going to call it from where clause. Anyway I consider our polemic fruitful.